# Push notification with GCM and corresponding Chat Activity

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM in my application and I have tested via two android devices and it works. I am implementing a simple chat application within my app. My app is actually selling or buying products.

When a user wants to give a bid, then he types his message and send it to server and gcm is activated and seller receives the potential customer's message. When seller clicks on the received push notification message, it should take him to the chat activity. With this simple text message, how do I know which corresponding product?

Comment: Change notification image for each product

Comment: Are you sending the GCM with a server? Cause if you are, you probably have a data element called "message" to pass the message, you can add another element to pass "productId". This info can be retrieved from the extras in your intent service. I'll post an answer if you are using a server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've mentioned in the comments, if you are sending via a server you can do this:

```
$registatoin_ids = array($regId);
$message = array("message" => $message, "productId" => $uniqueProductId);

$result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
echo $result;
```

then in your intent service:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
String message = extras.getString("message");
String productId = extras.getString("productId");
```

When you go to build your notification:

```
Intent productWindow = new Intent(this, ProductActivity.class);
productWindow.putExtra("productId", productId);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,productWindow , 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could format your GCM messages in a specific way, so the message overhead is sent with a format that you know and then you can parse it and take any needed actions. For example, you could send your messages this way:

```
ProdID:123456,Action:Bid,...
```

You would take the comma (or any other sign) as separator, get the parts of it and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: but I do not want to show ProductID to the user in the push notification? Is it possible? ProductID is a uniqueID for each item

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, usually the push notification processing works in background, i.e., it's "transparent" to the user. The user would hit a button, and that button would get the product ID and any other information needed and create a `GCM` push message which you would then send to the remote server, but the user wouldn't notice that so the push notification wouldn't be shown to them.

Comment: I am asking about seller side, not buyer side. I could append product id in the server side when potential buyer send the message, it is pretty straightforward.The concern that I have, I do not want to show product id to the seller.

Comment: If you format the message in a specific way, you could get the message string and split it into parts using the separator (comma in my example). So, you could have an array like `["ProdID:123456", "Action:Bid", ...]` and get only the part of the messages that you want to show the users and do not include the rest of them.

Comment: thanks for further detail. Where could I parse gcm message in the seller side?

Comment: I would not recommend this as custom parsing is very "hacky"